# Closing paragraphs creating unwanted line breaks

Tags: css, html, paragraph

I am trying to make it so all the circles align across the page, but instead they are stacking vertically. Is there any way to remove the line break, or any other tools that will allow for the same CSS attributes that the CSS in my paragraph has? Would it be easier to implement a div instead?

```
<div>
    <p id="developer">
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    HTML
    <br>
    CSS
    <br>
    JavaScript & jQuery
    </p>

    <p id="designer">
            <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
        Photoshop
        <br>
            Illustrator
            <br>
                Responsive Design
    </p>

    <p id="uxdesigner">
        <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
        Flowcharts
        <br>
            Wireframes
            <br>
                Personas
    </p>
</div>

#developer {
    background-color: #0071BC;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    border-radius: 300px;
    text-align: center;

}
#designer {
    background-color: #0071BC;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    border-radius: 300px;
    text-align: center; 
}
#uxdesigner {
    background-color: #0071BC;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    border-radius: 300px;
    text-align: center; 
}
```

Comment: Do you want the p blocks to stack left to right? If so you'll need to change them with display: inline or display: inline-block.

Comment: @BrianDHall `display:inline` will not work, it'll collapse the entire object and all its children down to an inline mess.

Comment: yes, I wanted to p blocks to stack left to right. I changed it to your suggestion, it now works. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Add:

```
p {
    display:inline-block;
}
```

As a sidenote, please keep layout in your CSS files, and don't use HTML elements for it. Specifically creating spacing with `<br>` is a bad idea and a semantic disaster.

Answer (score 0):

You could get extra value out of using `display: table` in this case. Here is a much cleaner version of your code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<style media="all">

.skills {display: table;}
.skills p {
    display: table-cell; 
    vertical-align: middle; 
    background-color: #0071BC;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    border-radius: 300px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0;
}
.skills span {display: block;}

</style>

</head>
<body>

<div class="skills">
    <p>
        <span>HTML</span>
        <span>CSS</span>
        <span>JavaScript & jQuery</span>
    </p>

    <p>
        <span>Photoshop</span>
        <span>Illustrator</span>
        <span>Responsive Design</span>
    </p>

    <p>
        <span>Flowcharts</span>
        <span>Wireframes</span>
        <span>Personas</span>
    </p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```